# Android Studio Android DDMS display issue

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, ddms

I'm using Android Studio 0.7 and while i normally find it quite pleasant to work with, its logcat support is intermittent at best. Now i've somehow gotten myself into a bit of an interface conundrum. Something i did inadvertently with the Android DDMS window at the bottom has meant that "Devices" and "logcat", which are normally in a two-paned window together (e.g. "Devices | logcat"), have become separate. As a result i can no longer view the filter box and the logcat output without switching panes, which as you can imagine is a real PAIN! (pun unintended but welcomed)

Here are some screenshots - at the top you see two shots of the two panes in their current separated form in v0.7, and below you see what it normally looks like (from v0.8). It's like i've somehow lost the whole header for the individual panes...

[image: Android Studio Screenshots]

I've looked at all the buttons nearby, looked through all the settings, and googled as best i can, and i just can't figure it out. Can anybody help me? At the moment i can only hope that google fixes their developer L preview so i can actually start using 0.8 but who knows how long that will be....

Answer (score 0):

In Intellij IDEA 13.1.5 for Mac, press Fn in keyboard, drag 'Devices' window to 'logcat' window, done!

Answer (score 0):

Click and drag the part I highlighted in Red. When it becomes a separate box, just close it by clicking on the X on the top right. 
[image]